# React Native - rerender child component from parent component

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, rendering, parent-child

I am trying to modify a calendar - https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars so that when I press a day, the background and text colors change for that day. I read that to re-render a component you need to update the state of the parent component, so that is what I am trying:

Parent.js

```
export default class InitiateRent extends Component {
  state = {
    ....
    this.markedDays: {},
    someVar: 0
  };

  constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.markedDays = {};
  }

  ....

  handler(e) {
    console.log('handler running');
    this.setState({
      someVar: 123
    })
  }

  <Calendar 
    handler={this.handler}
    markedDates={this.markedDays}
    onDayPress={(day)=> {
      console.log('selected day', day);

      var dateString = `'${day.year}-${day.month}-${day.day}'`

      var addDate = {
        [dateString]: {
          customStyles: {
            container: {
              backgroundColor: '#6de3dc',
            },
            text: {
              color: 'white',
              fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
          },
        }
      }

      this.markedDays = Object.assign(addDate, this.markedDays);

      console.log(this.markedDays);
    }}

....
```

Child.js

```
pressDay(date) {
    this.props.handler();
    this._handleDayInteraction(date, this.props.onDayPress);
}

renderDay(day, id) { //GETS CALLED IN CHILD RENDER METHOD VIA AN INTERMEDIARY
    ....
        <DayComp
          ....
          onPress={this.pressDay}
          ....
}
```

Everything functions correctly except I don't get the expected result - when I press a date on the calendar, the handler fires, the state changes, and in the console my object looks correct:

```
Object

'2018-9-23': {customStyles: {container: {backgroundColor: "#6de3dc"}, text: {color: "white", fontWeight: "bold"}}}

'2018-9-26': {customStyles: {container: {backgroundColor: "#6de3dc"}, text: {color: "white", fontWeight: "bold"}}}

'2018-9-28': {customStyles: {container: {backgroundColor: "#6de3dc"}, text: {color: "white", fontWeight: "bold"}}}

'2018-9-29': {customStyles: {container: {backgroundColor: "#6de3dc"}, text: {color: "white", fontWeight: "bold"}}}
```

But the background of the day on the calendar doesn't change, neither does the text - what do I have to do to get it to re-render (change)?

**UPDATE**

I created a chain of handlers all the way from the very bottom `day` component which represents just a day on the calendar all the way up to the highest order parent view (not App.js, but just below it) and that still did nothing.

**UPDATE**

The calendar is on a modal, and I don't have any handler on that updating its state, could that be the problem?

**UPDATE**

I found this in the docs:

> !Disclaimer! Make sure that markedDates param is immutable. If you
> change markedDates object content but the reference to it does not
> change calendar update will not be triggered.

What does this mean?

**UPDATE**

I tried to interpret what that meant with some google searches, does this make `this.state.markedDays` immutable?:

```
                const markedDays = this.state.markedDays;

                var dateString = `'${day.year}-${day.month}-${day.day}'`;

                var addDate = {
                  [dateString]: {
                    customStyles: {
                      container: {
                        backgroundColor: '#6de3dc',
                      },
                      text: {
                        color: 'white',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                      },
                    },
                  }
                }

                const markedDaysHolder = {
                  ...markedDays,
                  ...addDate
                }
                
                this.state.markedDays = markedDaysHolder;
```

**UPDATE**

I put:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  console.log("componentDidUpdate in InitiateRent:", prevProps, prevState, snapshot);
}
```

The output of the above is:

```
componentDidUpdate in InitiateRent: (3) (index.bundle, line 761)

{initiateRentMessage: function, modalHeight: 200, modalWidth: 200, handler: function}

{modalVisible: true, message: "Hi, I would like to rent an item from you.", rentButtonBackground: "#6de3dc", someVar: 123, markedDays: Object}

undefined
```

I can see the state object `markedDays` getting bigger with each button press from this output, why isn't the style changing?

In all the relevant components, and I noticed it doesn't fire on the lowest order component, which is the one that needs to change.

Comment: You shouldn't do something like this this.state.markedDays = markedDaysHolder. Always use setState to update the state objects. Using setState re-renders the component and all the child components.

Comment: thanks good catch, i made the change but  no luck, updating my quesiton with something else i found

Comment: use React.PureComponent and define your state within constructor

  constructor() {
    super(); 
this.state = {
    ....
    this.markedDays: {},
    someVar: 0
  };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.markedDays = {};
  }

Comment: you mean to do `this.state = { .... this.markedDays: {}`? did u mean  `this.state = { .... markedDays: {}`? or am i supposed to be using this in the the state?

Comment: constructor(){ super(); this.state = { defineStateVariablesHere: true }}

Comment: @HaiderAli still nothing...i also noticed that for some reason it doesn't record the first date select in `this.state.markedDays`, but records the second one and the rest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180554/discussion-between-haider-ali-and-ewizard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem, this is what you need to do

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }
    this.onDayPress = this.onDayPress
  }

showCalendar = () => {
    return (
      <Calendar
        onDayPress={this.onDayPress}
        style={styles.calendar}
        hideExtraDays
        markedDates={{
          [this.state.selected]: {
            selected: true,
            disableTouchEvent: true,
            selectedDotColor: 'orange',
          },
        }}
      />
    )
  }

onDayPress = day => {
    this.setState({
      selected: day.dateString,
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the flushed out answer for what I was trying to do. I wanted to be able to select and deselect a date by pressing on it (deselecting being the issue after @HaiderAli helped):

All I had to do was:

```js
onDayPress = (day) => {
  const _selectedDay = day.dateString;
  let marked = true;
  if (this.state._markedDates[_selectedDay]) {
    // Already in marked dates, so reverse current marked state
    marked = !this.state._markedDates[_selectedDay].selected;
    console.log('marked:', marked);
  }
          
  // Create a new object using object property spread since it should be immutable
  // Reading: https://davidwalsh.name/merge-objects
  const updatedMarkedDates = {
    ...this.state._markedDates,
    ...{
      [_selectedDay]: {
        'selected': marked,
        customStyles: {
          container: {
            backgroundColor: '#6de3dc',
          },
          text: {
            color: 'white',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          },
        },
      }
    }
  }

  // Triggers component to render again, picking up the new state
  this.setState({ _markedDates: updatedMarkedDates });
}
```

I added `'selected':`, which needs to be there and this function improves @HaiderAli's answer.

To get the deselecting to work, open `node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/calendar/day/custom/index.js` (This is the wrong file for you if you aren't using `markingType={'custom'}` prop on the calendar. If you aren't using the prop, edit `node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/calendar/day/basic/index.js`). Make this change:

```
....

render() {
    let containerStyle = [this.style.base];
    let textStyle = [this.style.text];

    let marking = this.props.marking || {};
    if (marking && marking.constructor === Array && marking.length) {
      marking = {
        marking: true
      };
    }
    const isDisabled = typeof marking.disabled !== 'undefined' ? marking.disabled : this.props.state === 'disabled';

    console.log('marking in day:', marking.selected);

    if (marking.selected) {
      containerStyle.push(this.style.selected);
    } else if (isDisabled) {
      textStyle.push(this.style.disabledText);
    } else if (this.props.state === 'today') {
      containerStyle.push(this.style.today);
      textStyle.push(this.style.todayText);

    /********ADD THIS CONDITION********/
    } else if(!marking.selected) { 
      textStyle.push({backgroundColor: '#ffffff', color: '#2d4150'});
    }

....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Calendar, CalendarList, Agenda } from 'react-native-calendars';

const Calender = () => {
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState();

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <Calendar
        style={[styles.calendar, { height: 350 }]}
        onDayPress={(day) => {
          setSelectedDay({ selected: day.dateString });
        }}
        enableSwipeMonths={true}
        markedDates={{
          [selectedDay?.selected]: {
            selected: true,
            disableTouchEvent: true,
            selectedDotColor: 'orange',
          },
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Calender;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.This question is asked more than 4 years ago and it has accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer