# React-Native: how to bind item in component with item in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bind, react-navigation

I am trying to build a calendar using [react-native-calendars library by wix](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars).
For instance, when I click on 5 Dec, 2018 in `Calendar Component`, it should navigate to 5 Dec, 2018 on `Agenda Component`. This is what I am trying to do.

This is my code for `Calendar Component` where I am trying to grab the id and bind it:

```
    class Calendar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
         this.state = {
             active: 'true'
         }
    }

    render() { 
        const {onSelect} = this.props;
        return ( 
            <View>
                <CalendarList 
                    keyExtractor = {day=>day.id}
                    onDayPress={(day) => {onSelect.bind(this, day)}}
                    pastScrollRange={12}
                    futureScrollRange={12}
                    scrollEnabled={true}
                    showScrollIndicator={true}
                />
            </View>
         );
    }
}

Calendar.propTypes = {
    onSelect: PropTypes.func,
}
```

This is my code `CalendarScreen` where I am doing the navigation.

```
const CalendarScreen = ({navigation}) => (
    <View >
        <Calendar  navigation={navigation} 
            onSelect={(id)=>{
            navigation.navigate('Agenda', {id}) }}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="#28F1A6" />
        </Calendar >
    </View>
);

Calendar.propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default CalendarScreen;
```

I also the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448375/react-native-rerender-child-component-from-parent-component/52451333#52451333). But no luck.

**EDIT:**

This is my `Agenda Component`

```
    class WeeklyAgenda extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: {}
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{height:600}}>
             <Agenda
                items={this.state.items}
                loadItemsForMonth={this.loadItems.bind(this)}
                selected={Date()}
                renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
                renderEmptyDate={this.renderEmptyDate.bind(this)}
                rowHasChanged={this.rowHasChanged.bind(this)}
                onRefresh = {() => { this.setState({refeshing : true})}}
                refreshing = {this.state.refreshing}
                refreshControl = {null}
                pastScrollRange={1}
                futureScrollRange = {3}
            />
    );
  }
```

This is `AgendaScreen`

```
    const AgendaScreen = ({navigation}) => (
    <View style={{height: 100}}>
        <WeeklyAgenda  navigation={navigation}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="#28F1A6" />
        </WeeklyAgenda >
    </View>
);

WeeklyAgenda.propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default AgendaScreen;
```

Comment: Are you getting error messages?

Comment: @RachelGallen No, no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calender passes CalenderScreen a callback onSelect(id).

Calender screen only needs to call onSelect(day).

```
onDayPress={(day) => {onSelect(day)}}
```

Or make the callback accept both the navigation object and the day

```
onDayPress={(day) => {onSelect(day, navigation)}}
```

Calender should now set

```
onSelect={(day, navigation)=>{
        navigation.navigate('Agenda', {day}) }}>
```

Or as you are passing the navigation object to Calender why pass a callback

```
onDayPress={(day) => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Agenda', {day})}}
```

Edit: new classes, and changed id to day

Same problem. onSelect navigates to AgentScreen and passes it the navigation prop (witha the day object in it), and in turn, AgentScreen passes the navigation prop to WeeklyAgent, but WeeklyAgent doesn't use the navigation prop to get the id.

```
selected={Date()}
```

Creates a new date object with todays date.
To get the correct date you need to get the day from navigation, usually something along the lines of

```
this.props.navigation.state.params["day"]
```

returns the date passed.

Now if WeeklyAgenda doesn't actually use navigation further, i wouldn't pass it.

Instead Weekly agenda should have a prop 'day', so instead of

```
 <WeeklyAgenda  navigation={navigation}>
```

try

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
...
<WeeklyAgenda  day={params["day"}>
```

The first line unpacks the params object from state into a variable called params.

WeeklyAgenda would now do

```
selected={this.props.day}
```

I don't think the problem here is the binding at all. 
I'd recommend reading this [article](https://medium.com/shoutem/react-to-bind-or-not-to-bind-7bf58327e22a) or another on what the binding does.

Comment: thanks for your response. With either of these methods, I can navigate from `CalendarScreen` to `AgendaScreen` but I am unable to go say, from 20th Dec on `CalendarScreen` to 20th Dec on `AgendaScreen.` It does navigate but just takes me to the current date.

Comment: Without looking at AgendaScreen, it's hard to say why. Are you sure you are passing the the correct day? in AgendaScreen print the id from navigation. Is AgendaScreen using id to set the date?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am an absolute beginner to react-native. I have updated my description with `Agenda Component` and `AgendaScreen`. I am obviously missing out something, but not sure what exactly

Comment: `WeeklyAgenda` does uses navigation further. It navigates to reminders page with the selected date.

Comment: You could pass a callback instead, like onDayPress